# How to show tool tip while hovering the matoptions based on a condition?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<mat-select class="dropBox" placeholder="Select One" (selectionChange)="mymethod($event.value)" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of myList" [value]="option" matTooltip="{{option}}>
                             {{option}}
                     </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
```

I want to display the tool tip for some of the options in myList and not all.  Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following array :

```
foods: Food[] = [
{value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
{value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza', tooltip: "hey"},
{value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
];
```

Then in your select

```
 <mat-select>
  <mat-option  *ngFor="let food of foods"
    [value]="food.value"
    [matTooltip]="food.tooltip"
  >
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to wrap the text in the options. Because if the text is too long then a part of the text  is not visible in the option. Can you show how to wrap the text in the options.

Comment: Edited to make it even simpler. I don't know how to wrap the text. maybe apply a CSS style. on StackBlitz the text wraps automaticaly